# Mail function for removing the server address - PHP

Tags: php, email, email-formats

I need to know how to remove the server address in the email.

Ex:`someone@example.com` via server address. I just wanna remove the via part .

```
mail($to,$subject1,$replymessage, $headers ,"-f abc@example.com")
```

Doesn't work for me

Comment: Are you on a shared hosting?

Comment: yes.. we are on shared hosting.Do you have any idea??

Comment: The sendmail on that server needs to be configured to accept `-f` from your php process AND it needs to allow sending from the domain of your choice; this is most likely not going to work for your shared host.

Comment: Don't use ALL CAPS titles please.

Comment: it will be in the mail headers anyway, and on a shared host you don't have all the control you may want.